# Can the tab bar (using UITabBarController) go above iAds (or any banner ad)?

Tags: iphone, tabbar, ads

I have a tab bar app that I want to add a banner ad to. I have read another answer about how to add the ad, but it didn't talk about where. It seems the most obvious position would be between the tab bar and my content, but it seems a little disruptive to put the ad between two parts of my interface. I could also put it at the top of the screen, but there are reasons why I don't prefer to do that.

Is there a way I can move the tab bar up to make space for the ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the frame of a tabbar controller's view is **really** painful.

I once considered doing it for some reason and found Adam's answer to [Subclass UITabBarController to adjust it's frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815059/subclass-uitabbarcontroller-to-adjust-its-frame) very helpful.

But keep in mind that `UITabBarController` is doing a lot of magic behind (like resizing itself and its view controllers' views at different times) and that it may change with future versions of the OS.

Changing the default behavior of Apple's UI components can also be ground to AppStore rejections (so far I've never seen iAd banners put below the tab bar.)